# Problem with numeric integration

Tags: integral-equations

I am having trouble with the `UnitStep` function as in the title. My problem is very simple, but I am not able to get a numerical result.

I have

```
f1[y] = 1/(E^((-1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])

g1[y] = (1.0028877725946312*^6*UnitStep[-7.963235463105154 - y])/
   E^((-1 + y)^2/2) + (0.12147136083763578*UnitStep[-7.963235463105154 + y])/
      E^((-1 + y)^2/2) + 
         1.001393070562657*
            (0.3484061634773921*Sqrt[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/2)] + 
                0.3484061634773921*Sqrt[E^(-(1 + y)^2/2)])^2*
            (-UnitStep[-7.963235463105154 + y] + UnitStep[7.963235463105154 + y])
```

and I want to solve the problem

$$N\left[\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{f1[y]}-\sqrt{g1[y]}\right)^2dy\right]$$

However, I did not get any result although I waited for a long time. I can plot $g1$ without any problem as well as $f1$, but I can not calculate the simple integral.

Comment: there is a syntax error in your definition. Try `f1[y_] =` instead of `f1[y] =`

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke You mean `f1[y_]:=`, but as long as the `NIntegrate` uses `y`, that actually doesn't matter. I suspect the real problem is trying to use `N[Integrate[...]]` instead of `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @Xerxes: in this case `Set` and `SetDelayed` are both fine. But you have a point with the `N[Integrate[...]]` construct.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke even if I change to the other syntax I still have the same problem.

Comment: You should post the code you are trying to use to integrate

Comment: @Rojo I couldnt because it is running forever. Is there a way to get the equation in this case?

Comment: I mean the code you are trying to run and runs forever

Comment: @Rojo I use the integral symbol and everything is exactly the same as the formula i typed.

Comment: Ah, got it. Well, you have your answer. When you wrap `N` outside of an integral, it first tries to evaluate it symbolically and only after it realises it can't (or until it succeeds), it tries numerical. Using `NIntegrate` it is done numerically from the start. The symbolic attempt is what takes long

Comment: The integral symbol is the same as `Integrate[...]`, as you can see by right clicking on the cell and Convert to -> InputForm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using your definitions (using the placeholder pattern `f1[y_]` instead of the absolute pattern `f1[y]` is usually a good idea if you want to use it as a function that works with numerical values, too. Also using `:=` (`SetDelayed`) instead of `=` (`Set`) inserts the left hand side value `y` into the definition every time you use it, which is closer to the behavior you would expect from a function):

```
f1[y_] := 1/(E^((-1 + y)^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])

g1[y_] := (1.0028877725946312*^6*UnitStep[-7.963235463105154 - y])/
   E^((-1 + y)^2/2) + (0.12147136083763578*
     UnitStep[-7.963235463105154 + y])/E^((-1 + y)^2/2) + 
  1.001393070562657*(0.3484061634773921*Sqrt[E^(-(-1 + y)^2/2)] + 
      0.3484061634773921*
       Sqrt[E^(-(1 + y)^2/2)])^2*(-UnitStep[-7.963235463105154 + y] + 
     UnitStep[7.963235463105154 + y])
```

you could compute the integral via

```
(1/2) NIntegrate[(Sqrt[f1[y]]-Sqrt[g1[y]])^2, {y,-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
(* 0.10271 *)
```

Using `NIntegrate` can save a lot of time, since Mathematica then knows that you are interested in a numerical solution from the start and doesn't waste time trying to find an analytical solution (Thanks to Xerxes and Rojo for pointing that out).

Comment: great! So my mistake was using the symbols. I guess in this case mathematica is searching first the algebraic solution and then trying to convert it to numerical value. Thanks alot.

Comment: Unless you `Clear[y]` prior to running this code, it is not safe to use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`. Consider `y=banana;f[y_]=y;f[0.1]`. `(* banana *)`

Comment: good point, i'll change the code for robustness.